# azure datafactory dataflow variable alternativ

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need your help to solve a technical problem in ADF Dataflow.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQkxx.png)
[my_dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8zrd.png)

I need to merge rows where the dates cross or touch each other. The problem is that I can't manipulate a variable to increment in dataflow to get the following result (in yellow).

This result would allow me to group the rows together.

I don't know how implement it into dataflow

The logic will be : 
*CASE(nrow == 1, my_variable = 1,

endDate > startDate-1 || endDate == startDate-1,my_variable, 

my_variable + 1*
)

Do you have a solution to work around this problem?

Comment: Could you please edit the question to add what you have tried so far and the error that you are getting.

Comment: I try to give you more informations .... Not easy when i dont really error message !